# SBT installation errors

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-sources

While installing sbt I am encountering these errors

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I opened `sbt.list` 
it has these two lines:

```
deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/
deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/
```

It is missing distribution and component details. How should I alter it to fix the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Looking on their [site for SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html), you are missing a space at the end of your deb line before the backslash.  And you only need one line:

```
deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanx man it works